# QPropertyAnimation on widget opacity restarts on resize causing the window to blink/flicker

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpropertyanimation

I have this code as follows:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w    = QWidget()
    eff  = QGraphicsOpacityEffect(w)
    anim = QPropertyAnimation(eff, b"opacity")
    btn  = QPushButton("Button", w)
    btn.clicked.connect(w.close)

    eff.setOpacity(0)
    w.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    w.setGraphicsEffect(eff)
    w.show()

    anim.setDuration(10000)
    anim.setStartValue(0)
    anim.setEndValue(1)
    anim.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It works fine (fade in effect). However, when I resize the window, the animation restarts, causing the window to blink/flicker during resize. If I remove the call to animate after the call to show, no more blink (but no more fade in).

Moreover, after some time, resizing to a much bigger size causes a white rectangle over a black background to be displayed.

Is there something I am missing?

---

**UPDATE**

This is the behavior I am looking for (background remains white, i.e. opacity=1, after the animation run once). Works with the following code but does not look like best practice to do it like this.

```
import sys, time

from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.w = QWidget()
        self.w.setMinimumSize(400,400)
        self.w.resizeEvent = self.selfOnResize # added this

    def animate(self):
        self.eff  = QGraphicsOpacityEffect(self.w)
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.eff, b"opacity")
        self.btn  = QPushButton("Button", self.w)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.w.close)

        self.eff.setOpacity(0)
        self.w.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.w.setGraphicsEffect(self.eff)
        self.w.show()

        self.anim.setDuration(100000)
        self.anim.setStartValue(0)
        self.anim.setEndValue(1)
        self.anim.start()

    # this fixes the issue but looks like a dirty hack
    def selfOnResize(self, event):
        self.eff.setOpacity(1) 
        # print(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.animate()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: From what I understand that you put 100000 to indicate that there is a flicker when you resize the widget when the animation is still active, am I correct?

Comment: @eyllanesc 1. yes, sorry that was a bad copy paste. 2. Not quite, it's more to check that the "flicker" is directly related to the animation, because when I resize, the animation seems to restart. The animation stops. Then when I resize, it seems to restart and cause the flickering while resizing.

Comment: @eyllanesc simplified the question and added a working full example. Seems the issue is resizing causes repaint and repaint causes the animation to run again.